# Icon not showing up in taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I have a windows form application. When I set the form's icon property to an icon I made, it uses this image correctly during a debug session on the form, in the taskbar, and in the system tray. However when I make a shortcut to the program's executable or pin the program to my taskbar it doesn't use the icon image I set in the form's properties, it uses a default icon instead for the icon in the taskbar, but on the form and in the system tray it is using the icon I made and set to it. What am I missing here?

Comment: Yup. Mine is more or less a duplicate of that. That person was having trouble simply finding all his available icon files, but the solution is the same one I needed. Didn't find that question in my research earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the icon in the project properties as well (rightclick->properties->application->symbol and manifest). It then should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get to it using your right click method (might be a difference in versions) but for anyone else looking at this question, I did Project -> Properties -> application -> icon and manifest